# database configuration in pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I tried to create a sqlalchemy project in pyramid and when I run the server, I get this error,

```
Pyramid is having a problem using your SQL database.  The problem
might be caused by one of the following things:

1.  You may need to run the "initialize_MyProject_db" script
    to initialize your database tables.  Check your virtual 
    environment's "bin" directory for this script and try to run it.

2.  Your database server may not be running.  Check that the
    database server referred to by the "sqlalchemy.url" setting in
    your "development.ini" file is running.

After you fix the problem, please restart the Pyramid application to
try it again.
```

when I check my development.ini file the sqlite database is configured as this,

```
sqlalchemy.url = sqlite:///%(here)s/MyProject.sqlite
```

What needs to changed in here to configure it correctly?

I run on linux box.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a database in either sqlite,postgres,or any other,Thereafter go to `development.ini` file edit `sqlalchemy.url = sqlite:///%(here)s/MyProject.sqlite` and specify the name of your database,then run the `initialize_myproject_db` `development.ini` command.if you are using mysql, that line should be
  sqlachemy.uri = mysql://username:password@host/dbname

Answer (score 2):

Just trying Pyramid for the first time, I just faced the same problem, after many command combinations, I just got the solution.

Run from the **project root**, the command:

```
initialize_tutorial_db development.ini
```

Info taken from [Wiki2 SQLAlchemy tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/installation.html#initializing-the-database)

Comment: +1 for the link to the doc, just note that the name of the script depends on the project name (`tutorial` should be replaced with the project name)

Answer (score 1):

It says right there in the first point - you need to run initialize_MyProject_db development.ini to create database.
If that's not the case please post the log from running the server.